# Suppose $f(x)\in C^1[a,b]$, and $f(x)\neq 0$ in $a\leq x\leq b$, then $\left|\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx\right|=\int_{a}^{b}|f(x)|dx$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions, derivatives, continuity

My question is : Suppose $f(x)\in C^1[a,b]$, and $f(x)\neq 0$ in $a\leq x\leq b$, then $$\left|\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx\right|=\int_{a}^{b}|f(x)|dx \tag{1}$$
My try: Since $f(x)\in C^1[a,b]$ and $f(x)\neq 0$ in $a\leq x\leq b$ so $f(x)$ cannot change its sign in $[a,b]$. Otherwise by Location of roots theorem there exist atleast one $c\in(a,b)$ such that $f(c)=0$ which violates $f(x)\neq 0$ in $a\leq x\leq b$ .

But then why is the extra condition $f(x)\in C^1[a,b]$ given. It seems to be true in the mild condition that $f(x)\in C[a,b]$?

Comment: You're right, $f\in C^0([a,b])$ is enough.

Comment: @peek-a-boo And is my proof fine?

Comment: sure, the idea is just intermediate-value theorem which implies a nowhere vanishing continuous function has the same sign everywhere.